# Harry Potter fanfic with Ron/mute Hermione, recovery from Imprisonment, has sequel on fanfiction.net

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

Does anyone remember the name or author of a popular fanfic on fanfiction.net (several hundred favs) in which Ron spends a few chapters believing Hermione to be dead, but she remains hostage by Bellatrix?

It was a completed fic of probably 30 chapters, written in third person, no changes in POV. I’m 90% sure it was classified as Angst of fanfiction.net, because I read it during a moody binge.

Ron thinks Hermione is dead, but is later imprisoned himself. He notices a mute girl in the dungeons with him and over time realizes it’s Hermione. Hermione can't control her magic and will blast things accidentally when given a wand. Hermione is mute for most of the fic, but when she does regain some capacity, the author wrote out her stuttering phonetically. They do spend some time recovering at Shell Cottage, and her recovery is marked by severe headaches.

The fic culminates at the Battle of Hogwarts which keeps to canon mostly; Hermione tries to help but is held in the nursing wing. In the sequel (last I checked, 8 chapters, in progress), she continues to recover and I feel there’s a line of “but what if I never get better” to Ron. There’s also a funeral scene, where the trio catch Draco observing from afar, and Narcissa wanting to see how Hermione was recovering as she felt guilty for imprisoning Hermione in her house.

Answer (score 5):

I believe these are what you are looking for:

[*Almost Everything I Wished I'd Said*](https://fanfiction.net/s/6288599/1/Almost-Everything-I-Wished-I-d-Said) ([archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20181105012319/https://www.fanfiction.net/s/6288599/1/Almost-Everything-I-Wish-I-d-Said)).

With a sequel:

[*Light Outside*](https://fanfiction.net/s/9745685/1/Light-Outside) ([archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20181106192155/https://www.fanfiction.net/s/9745685/1/Light-Outside)).

I have read them both a couple of times now and recognized the story from your description. Unfortunately, I don't know that these stories are available anymore - the links say the stories are unavailable. I hope that's temporary.

Comment: The first chapter of both (and some other random chapters) are available on Archive.org: [Almost Everything I Wish I'd Said](https://web.archive.org/web/20181105012319/https://www.fanfiction.net/s/6288599/1/Almost-Everything-I-Wish-I-d-Said); [Light Outside](https://web.archive.org/web/20181106192155/https://www.fanfiction.net/s/9745685/1/Light-Outside).

Comment: Thanks very much for the updated links!

Comment: The author (hey-torch) seems to have deleted their account and is now listed as GoneAF. I created an account on fanfic.net to try and private message to ask if they had a copy remaining but messages are disabled. I don't hold out much hope, which is a shame because it was one of my favourites :(

Answer (score 0):

Everyone - I found it! If you download the fanfiction archive from [this link](https://archive.org/download/fanfictiondotnet_repack) by clicking on the section that says Fanfiction_Harry_Potter.zip, you'll be able to see the fanfic. It takes forever to download because it is such a gigantic file, but once you have it installed, just open the folder titled "Completed" and it will be there under the name "Harry Potter - hey-torch - Almost Everything I Wish I'd Said.txt"

Comment: Could you [edit] your answer to explain how this matches the OP’s description? Seeing as you have the text for the story adding in quotes where applicable would also greatly improve this.